# For Msp430 controller coding

Tags: c++, c, gcc, msp430, code-composer

".x.c.swp .ccsproject .cdtbuild .cdtproject .project x.c x.h hardware.h .cmd readme.txt" these are the files given as a source file for my evaluation board.
How can i approach these files?

Comment: I would try it with a polite "Hi. How are you?". sorry... it is not sooo clear what is your question.

Comment: code composer studio?

Comment: You should find a copy of Code Composer Studio (CCS) which is a Texas Instruments' (TI) IDE for embedded development. It's based on Eclipse. I have only used it commercially, but I think you can get free student/non-profit licenses for it, but am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following list of files:

```
.x.c.swp .ccsproject .cdtbuild .cdtproject .project x.c x.h hardware.h .cmd readme.txt
```

I cannot be absolutely sure, as I do not have have the actual files infront of me. but here is my (based on experience) expectation:

```
x.c
a C source code file
shows how to write a C source file for the MSP430

x.h
a C header file for the `x.c` source file
shows how to write a C header file for the MSP430

hardware.h
a header file that contains: 
all the peripheral addresses
names for all the hardware registers the compiler will recognize
for the MSP430

.x.c.swp
This is a file created by the editing of the `x.c` file
you can ignore this file

.ccsproject
.cdtbuild
.cdtproject
.project
skeletons of files that the Code Composer Studio IDE 
will create when a `project` for your program is created
A project is a way to keep a list of the files (and related info) about a program in one place

.cmd
This is a skeleton linker command file for any MSP430 program
The documentation will tell you how to write a `project.cmd` file
for your own program.

readme.txt
This is a text file that tells you some details about the files,
that were supplied by the manufacture of the IDE and the MSP430
```

Comment: Thank you for your response this gives me to an idea about the  files i have and how to approach those files.